# Can you please help me with my on step behind issue in my vue code?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, vuetify.js

I got a question about my vue code I'm making a filter dropdown but when I input a key to trigger the key down event for filtering the arr it's changing the dom each time after the second event (one step behind).

Here is the code pen :

https://codepen.io/dyonvangerwen/pen/zYvjMdY

it's only keeping  the values in the arr that are matching the input

template:

```
<div id="app">
  <v-app id="inspire">
    <v-form>
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="12" sm="6" md="3">
            <v-text-field
              v-model="inputValue"         
              label="Filled"
              placeholder="Placeholder"
              filled
              v-on:keydown="tester"
            ></v-text-field>
         <v-card
    class="mx-auto"
    max-width="400"
    tile
  >
    <v-list-ite >
      <v-list-item-content v-for=" item in itemsInDropdown" :key="item">
        <v-list-item-title>{{item}}</v-list-item-title>
      </v-list-item-content>
    </v-list-ite>


     </v-card>
          </v-col>

        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>
  </v-app>
</div>
```

script:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  vuetify: new Vuetify(),
  data: () => ({
    inputValue:'',
    itemsInDropdown:['a','b','c','d','e','ab','cd','ea']
  }),
  methods:{
    tester:function(){
      this.itemsInDropdown = this.itemsInDropdown.filter((x)=>{
     if(x.includes(this.inputValue)){ 
        return true
        } 
        else{return false}
      })
    }
  }

})
```

Comment: I tried to remove the pleading from the title, and replace it with a summary of the problem, but I am not sure I understand what this is saying. Could "Issue with Vue code" be made more specific?

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `computed` in this case:

1. Replace the method with this:

```
computed:{
    itemsInDropdownFiltered:function(){
         return this.itemsInDropdown.filter((x)=>{
              return x.includes(this.inputValue);
         });
    }
}
```

2. Change the array to be rendered from `itemsInDropdown` to `itemsInDropdownFiltered` as follows:

```
<v-list-item-content v-for="item in itemsInDropdownFiltered" :key="item">
```